# Pressure exerted by each tyre

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, pressure, statics

See image. It is from an exam for 12/13 year olds, but I'm rather confused about it. Shouldn't the answer be approx 120,000 N/sq M, since the force is distributed equally over the three tyres? One would expect the pressure to decrease the more tyres that are added (ignoring the weight of the tyres), but if we just take 5500 N and divide it by the contact that each tyre makes with the ground, then it would always stay the same. This doesn't make intuitive sense to me.

[image]

Comment: You are , of course, quite right. Quite a tough question for 12/13 year olds, what with remembering $g$ and doing the unit conversion. Dividing by 3, the step that the question-setter forgot, is the easy bit! [I doubt, too, whether the wheels exert equal forces on the road, but you never know, the *Robin* is (or was) a very wonderful car!]

Comment: @PhilipWood Thank you, and yes, it's from a scholarship exam paper

Comment: Yes, I remember seeing this question in my 5th grade scholar exam.

Comment: @Math_Whiz :) https://www.westminster.org.uk/admissions/scholarships/the-challenge/

Comment: Not the standard one would expect of this institution. As well as no right answer being offered, the equal forces assumption is questionable and, more trivially, the force unit is newton (or N), but not Newton.

Comment: So what is the accepted answer because I am an engineer and I still get approx. 120kPa (120000 N/m^2). Only if the contact patch was 8.5×5.7 cm I would get **E** for the answer. Maybe the question meant to say **the combined area** is 15×10

Answer (score 1):

Well if the question was talking about the combined contact area then

> [image: pic]

The balance of forces is

$$ (550\text{ kg})(10 \;\mathrm{m/s^2}) = (0.15\text{ m})(0.10\text{ m})\;P $$

or

$$ P =  366667\;\mathrm{N/s^2} $$

which matches the answer (E).  So the question is erroneous.